# After upgrading canoo webtest to version 3.0, the verifyHeader test no longer works

Tags: java, web-testing, canoo, canoo-webtest

The browser page for the test displays

> Unexpected exception caught: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException.

The console log shows no errors.

I know the project is defunct, but I love the package and hope someone has a suggestion.

Comment: This email chain suggests the class is missing from the jar. https://www.mail-archive.com/webtest@lists.canoo.com/msg08248.html. My own testing verifies this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack, in case it is available in either the console output or in the log files (you can generate debug output for this). Moreover, add as much detail as you have on your build- / execution environment (including version numbers).

Comment: Sorry @MWiesner.  The console log shows no error.  The only report is on the HTML page canoo builds.

Comment: Version 3.0 of Canoo WebTest (the latest on their site.) I see the same problem in Unix and Windows 10.  Both environments are running java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a workaround.  If the original test looked like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<verifyHeader name="Content-Type" text="application/x-gzip"/>
```

You can replace it with this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<storeHeader name="Content-Type" property="contentType"/>
<verifyProperty name="contentType" text="application/x-gzip"/>
```